# Python Regex to extract meeting invite from Gmail Subject

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract the meeting date / time from meeting invites within Gmail's subject. Below is an example of a subject for a meeting invite:

```
Invitation: Bob / Carol Meeting @ Tue Oct 25, 2022 11:30am - 12pm (CST) (bob@example.org)
```

**What I would like to extract:**

```
Tue Oct 25, 2022 11:30am - 12pm (CST)
```

I think the pattern could simply start with the space after the "@" and end with the ")". My Regex is very rusty so would appreciate any help :)

Many thanks!

Comment: `/(@.*?\))/` something like that seems reasonable https://regex101.com is very helpful for understanding regular expressions

Comment: @CollinD That would include "@ " in the 1st match and also match "@example.org"

Comment: Thanks for the response and suggestion on regex101 - will use in future :)

Comment: Sure would. if this were more developed it'd be an answer instead of a 2-second comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - it should match everything after the "@ " and up to the end of the timezone ")"

```
import re

string = (
    'Invitation: Bob / Carol Meeting @ Tue Oct 25, 2022 11:30am - 12pm (CST) (bob@example.org)'
)
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=@ )[^)]+\)')
matches = re.findall(pattern, string)
print(matches)
# => 'Tue Oct 25, 2022 11:30am - 12pm (CST)'
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/qb2G5A/1) for a breakdown of the RegEx I used. Bear in mind that `re.findall` returns a *list* of matches, which is helpful if you want to scan a long multiline string of text and get all the matches at once. If you only care about the 1st match, you can get it by index e.g. `print(matches[0])`.

Comment: Note that you could technically optimize this further by making the matching lazy `[^)]+?` instead of greedy `[^)]+` (add the "?"), but that's probably overthinking it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't technically need regex for this.

Try the following:

```py
>>> s = 'Invitation: Bob / Carol Meeting @ Tue Oct 25, 2022 11:30am - 12pm (CST) (bob@example.org)'
>>> s[s.index('@') + 1 : s.rindex('(')].strip()
'Tue Oct 25, 2022 11:30am - 12pm (CST)'
```